# Using CSS and PHP Together

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have built a Wordpress plugin that requires to me to add CSS styles through the plugin's PHP file.

Is there a better way of doing this?  I can see this getting out of hand if not done properly.

```
function flags() {  

 <style type="text/css">

  <?php if(get_option('display')=='Vertical') { ?>
    <?php if (get_option('language_option')=='specific') { ?>
        #flags {display:none !important; }
    <?php } ?>
        p.hello { font-size:12px; color:darkgray; }
  <?php } ?>

 </style>     
<?php } 
}
```

Comment: I think this is missing some `echo` statements, isn't it?

Comment: I would move the conditions on the html instead of the CSS. Like having a high level `div class="vertical-or-not` somewhere.

Comment: @Sven No it is using templated PHP

Comment: @Sven why should there be an `echo`? everything outside the `<?php ?> ` is as if you would `echo` it at that place. That's why many libs leave out the last `?>` in the document and why php documents in utf-8 with BOM cause problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there isn't much CSS, a better way is to add body classes that allow you to target your selectors only when they are present:

```
<body class="display-vertical">    
  ...
```

And move the CSS from inline to the stylesheet:

```
.display-vertical #flags{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Just as I thought - simplicity always wins.  Thanks for the answer.